# Detecting whitespace in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

In a WinForms textbox with multiple whitespaces (e.g. 1 1 A), where, between the 1s, there is whitespace, how could I detect this via the string methods or regex?

Comment: Do you want to just detect it, or do something with it?

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you're trying to match.  Could you explian a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

use IndexOf

```
if( "1 1a".IndexOf(' ') >= 0 ) {
    // there is a space.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function should do the trick for you.

```
bool DoesContainsWhitespace()
{
   return textbox1.Text.Contains(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int NumberOfWhiteSpaceOccurances(string textFromTextBox){
 char[] textHolder = textFromTextBox.toCharArray();
 int numberOfWhiteSpaceOccurances = 0;
 for(int index= 0; index < textHolder.length; index++){
   if(textHolder[index] == ' ')numberOfWhiteSpaceOccurances++;
 }
 return numberOfWhiteSpaceOccurances;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty clear what the problem is, but in case you just want a way to tell if there is a white space anywhere in a given string, a different solution to the ones proposed by the other stack users (which also work) is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PatternFound("1 1 a"));
            Console.WriteLine(PatternFound("1     1    a"));
            Console.WriteLine(PatternFound("            1     1   a"));

        }

        static bool PatternFound(string str)
        {
            Regex regEx = new Regex("\\s");
            Match match = regEx.Match(str);
            return match.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

in case what you want is determining whether a given succession of consecutive white spaces appear, then you will need to add more to the regex pattern string.
Refer to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the options.

Answer (score -2):

I created a extension for a string to check for a letter or digit.

```
   public static partial class Extensions
    {
        public static bool IsAlphaNumericOnly(this string value)
        {
            return value.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit);
        }
    }
```

Using the extension:

```
string myString = " CheckMeOut";
bool check = myString.IsAlphaNumericOnly();  //Returns false

myString = "GoodData";
check = myString.IsAlphaNumericOnly();  //Returns true
```